# Redirecting on Form Validation Failure (Flask-WTForms)

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms, post-redirect-get

I'm trying to use Flask-WTF for a new form that I'm adding to a Flask app that I recently inherited.  I'm fairly new to the Flask ecosystem (completely new to WTForms), and I haven't done any web development in four years.

Example code in the Flask-WTF documentation renders a page on form validation failure, rather than redirecting ([Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).  At that point, a browser refresh would resubmit the previous POST.  This isn't good, right?  While most folks don't seem to give this scenario any attention, I do see a few people who feel like this is something to avoid (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250588/servlet-forward-on-post-validation-failure-and-post-redirect-get?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008546/jsf2-prg-and-validation-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

So how would I avoid this issue while using Flask-WTF?  If I redirect on validation failure, I think I lose the ability to show validation errors on each field.  Or perhaps I shouldn't worry about this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Personally never felt like this was an issue. I use `Flask-WTF` w/ `Flask-Bootstrap` and it highlights form field errors for me on a failed validation. If they try and resubmit the form it will fail again and never reaches the database level so you don't have to worry about the issue Post/Redirect/Get is trying to solve.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # add/update db. if form is invalid you never get here
        return redirect(url_for('success'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Comment: But it won't necessarily fail again in the future, if some state has changed since the previous request.